# How to transverse from parent element to child element in puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

```html
<div class="MuiGrid-root jss62 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12"><div class="MuiGrid-root jss107" style="background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(244, 67, 54) 40%, lightgrey 150%); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 1px 8px 8px; border: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);"><div class="MuiCardHeader-root"><div class="MuiCardHeader-avatar"><span class="material-icons MuiIcon-root jss112 MuiIcon-fontSizeLarge" aria-hidden="true">airplanemode_active</span></div><div class="MuiCardHeader-content"><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-title jss110 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Card-662</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-subheader jss111 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary MuiTypography-displayBlock">09/30/2021</span></div><div class="MuiCardHeader-action"><div><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Activate"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Edit"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 00-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="delete"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div></div></div><div class="MuiCardContent-root jss108"><h6 class="MuiTypography-root jss109 null MuiTypography-subtitle2">Card-661-description</h6></div></div><div class="MuiGrid-root jss107" style="background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(244, 67, 54) 40%, lightgrey 150%);"><div class="MuiCardHeader-root"><div class="MuiCardHeader-avatar"><span class="material-icons MuiIcon-root jss112 MuiIcon-fontSizeLarge" aria-hidden="true">airplanemode_active</span></div><div class="MuiCardHeader-content"><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-title jss110 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Card-661</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-subheader jss111 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary MuiTypography-displayBlock">09/30/2021</span></div><div class="MuiCardHeader-action"><div><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Activate" title="Activate"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Edit" title="Edit"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 00-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="delete" title="Delete"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div></div></div><div class="MuiCardContent-root jss108"><h6 class="MuiTypography-root jss109 null MuiTypography-subtitle2">Card-661-description</h6></div></div><div class="MuiGrid-root jss107" style="background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(244, 67, 54) 40%, lightgrey 150%);"><div class="MuiCardHeader-root"><div class="MuiCardHeader-avatar"><span class="material-icons MuiIcon-root jss112 MuiIcon-fontSizeLarge" aria-hidden="true">airplanemode_active</span></div><div class="MuiCardHeader-content"><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-title jss110 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-displayBlock">Card-64</span><span class="MuiTypography-root MuiCardHeader-subheader jss111 MuiTypography-body2 MuiTypography-colorTextSecondary MuiTypography-displayBlock">09/24/2021</span></div><div class="MuiCardHeader-action"><div><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Activate" title="Activate"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Edit" title="Edit"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 00-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss112 MuiIconButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="delete" title="Delete"><span class="MuiIconButton-label"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12zM19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div></div></div><div class="MuiCardContent-root jss108"><h6 class="MuiTypography-root jss109 null MuiTypography-subtitle2">Card-64-description</h6></div></div></div>
```

i wanted to navigate to element, where we have "Card-662"text. can anyone please help me with the xpath?

Comment: Try `//span[text()="Card-662"]`

Comment: hey actually its a dynamic data, so i cannot add specifically that name

Comment: Then maybe the first element of `//div[@class="MuiCardHeader-content"]/span` (or CSS selector `div.MuiCardHeader-content > span`).